# Round-robin tournament with 4 contestants per match and duplicates allowed

Tags: combinatorics

I need an algorithm that will calculate 4-contestant groups that ensure each contestant plays against each other contestant **at least once** but **more than once is allowed**.

This is different from a Steiner quadrupel where they're only allowed to meet once.

I tried the [circle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Circle_method) for pairwise matches but it doesn't translate well to quadrupel matches.

I'm looking for something slightly more optimized than just looping over the list of contestants.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a $(v,4,2)$-covering design, where $v$ is the number of people. In general, a $(v,k,t)$-covering design is a collection of $k$-element subsets of a $v$-element set with the property that every $t$-element subset is contained in some $k$-subset in the collection.

Dan Gordon maintains a database of the best known covering designs for parameters up to a certain size. Here is the data for $t=2$: https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/table.html#t=2 The $k=4$ column of that table gives the answer to your question. If you click on the entry in the $v^\text{th}$ row, you will see the best known $(v,4,2)$-covering design, so the best known possible answer to your question, for up to 99 people.

Comment: Thank you Mike, you've given me plenty to build on!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method for 28 players in twelve rounds.  There are 12 spare players in each of the first five rounds; they can be paired up as well.

It is key here that $28/4=7$ is prime, or at least coprime to $6$.

Divide the players into four groups of seven, players in each group numbered $1$ to $7$.  In the first five rounds, players play within each group $1234,1235,1236,1237,4567$.
In the next seven rounds, group A players each have a table they stay at.  Group B advances one table each round, Group C advances two tables each round, and Group D advances three tables each round.

Comment: Thanks Empy2 but this is too specific for my use case. I was looking for a more general solution that I could apply to an unknown number of players